# Question on proving relations

Tags: relations

State whether the following statement is true, and either prove it or provide a counter example:

Every Relation R on {0,1} satisfies R∘R subset of R.

This is a past paper question for an exam I have to sit tomorrow and I can't work out how to answer it.

After listing out the Relation R={(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)}, I can't work out what would happen if you apply the relation again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The notation R;R is unfamiliar to me. Is it the result of composing R with itself? (More commonly written R∘R.)

Comment: Yes, it is meant to be R∘R. That is just the way that it was written on the paper.

Comment: $R=\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$. Then $R∘R=\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the relation “different from”. I.e., $R=\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$.